# Server Error (500) when logging into admin panel

Tags: django

After deploying my project I have my project in `/svr` and when i go to login to my admin panel I get `Server Error (500)` I'm guessing this is because the permissions on my database are not correct.

I tried running `chown www-data db.sqlite3` but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Start by changing debug to True in settings.py

Comment: I thought that is a big no-no in production

Comment: Can you replicate the error on a non-production setup? As it generally is a bad idea, but debugging without it is essentially guessing.

Comment: It's no-no in production, but you can set up staging "production-like" environment with debug enabled to see which error causes 500